# Which way is better to verify the username and password in php

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say we are writing a login system and we want to check if the username and password provided by user match.

The data coming from browser is:

```
$username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
```

- One way to do so is to retrieve the data from database and then compare them with data coming from user.

  ```
  $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);        
  $stmt->execute();
  //...

  if($password = $dbpassword){
    //...
  }
  ```
- The other way around is to directly query the database (by embedding the variables into query statement) and then using the rowCount() to see if there is any record with the given username and password.

  ```
  $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password";
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
  $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
  $stmt->execute();
  $numRows = $stmt->rowCount();
  ```

I'm wondering wich way is better and why?

Comment: are you suggesting that in your first query you are bringing ALL users back from database and doing a compare row by row? The reason I ask is that you are comparing even the username. Secondly, are you saving your password as `cleartext` ?

Comment: Using a prepared statement as you do in the 2nd example is good practice. Also store only the salted password hash.

Comment: Don't use `strip_tags()`. If my password is `<bhjg3gtu3gb3hg3>` then an empty password will let someone in. Since you are using parameter binding, you don't need any more input filtering. (You might want to set a minimum length, and a generous maximum length, but that's a different matter).

Comment: if they are hashed why even set a max length? storage limits wont change (i hate sites not allowing my default 25 character (random) password.)

Comment: @ Drew Pierce no, in first query i find the record related to the username coming from the form, then i store the username (which i have already) and password (from database) inside some variable and compare them as the example above

Comment: @ halfer so you suggest in case of binding parameters we do not need input filtering?

Comment: You need input filtering for the username, but not for the password; as long as the password is hashed

Comment: [Proper Password Handling with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)

Comment: @varDumper: don't put a space in people's usernames - I did not get a notification here. For passwords, yes, no input filtering - you probably just want to set a minimum length (8?), and maximum length (200) and possibly a complexity requirement. See my profile if you want to see an end-to-end tutorial involving a login system.

Comment: Thanks @halfer - I'll fix!

Answer (score 2):

Assumming querying DB is a very heavy operation, you should query as few as possible. So the 2nd solution is good (only one query).

If rowcount return 0, then there is no username * password that correspond in the database.

Edit:
Always do queries that are the more accurate. There is no way to add code in the Php side if your database could do the same without additionals queries.

Comment: The 'edit' part is exactly what i'm asking. For checking username and password isn't it better to do some query directly from database in oppose to retrieving the data from database and compare them with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on hash you are using for storing passwords - for some advanced methods (like http://api.nette.org/2.2.0/source-Security.Passwords.php.html#24-49) you should use first option, because you need stored hash for verifying password.